# JavaScriptでiOSの機能を制御する方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript, ios, html

iPadでプログラミングが書きやすいソフトウェアキーボードを作りたいです。
HTMLとJavaScriptでソフトウェアキーボードは作れるのですが，
そのキーボードをiPadでも使いたいと考えています。
ソフトウェアキーボード自体はiPadでも動作が確認できるのですが、iOSだと従来のキーボードも一緒に出てきてしまいます。
この自動的に出てくる機能をオフにしたいのですが、
JavaScriptでiOSの制御はできるのでしょうか？

iPadでtextareaの部分をタッチすると自動的に出てきてしまうキーボードをJavaScriptやHTMLで抑える方法を教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

[Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) というライブラリがありますが、ここでの制御方法があるかもしれません。

JavaScript なら以下の様な記述でキーボードの表示を防げませんか？

```
let foo = function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.stopPropagation();
  //ここから続きの処理を書く…
}

textareaDOMObject.addEventListener('click', foo, false);
```